# jquery - search upwards for an element with a certain class?

Tags: jquery, parent

Is there a way in jquery to target `$(this)`.`some element above it`.with `class of 'abc'`

(by above, I mean parent, grandparent etc.)

for example:

```
<div class='a'>
    <div class='b'>
        <div class='c'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I click on class='c', Can i target anything above it with class='a', **and** get the same result as if I clicked class='b' with the same code? (if I click 'b', the 'a' div will still be its parent (or grandparent) with class of 'a')

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) :

```
$(this).closest('.a')
```

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Comment: if there are multiple `.a` divs nested then you may have to do something like 
`$(this).closest('.wrapper_above_a').find('.a');`

Answer (score 4):

`.parents` method could have a selector.

```
$(this).parents('.a')
```

Comment: Does this search upwards until it finds what is being sought after? Or only the immediate parenting div?

Comment: @iight - `.parents()` searches upwards, so does `.closest()`. The immediate parent div is accessed by using the singular `.parent()`

Comment: Thank you, @xdazz, I didn't see the 's' in parents. Also, thank you @ahren!

Comment: parents() will keep on searching up all the way to the document level and add all parent elements with that class to the selector.

Comment: @adeneo, you answer my next and most important question! Thank you!!